# Amazon RDS MySQL tmpdir location

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, magento-1.7, rds

We are facing a strange problem. We are running a Magento based store. In our admin, when we try to see orders, we are getting the error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 126 Incorrect key file for table '/rdsdbdata/tmp/#sql_20b_0.MYI'; try to repair it

After lot of research, I found that tmp folder has run out of space.

I executed the command:  show variables like '%tmpdir%'

And the value of folder was: `/rdsdbdata/tmp`

I ssh into my server and executed: `df -h`

This returned:

```
/dev/xvda1  mounted on  /

tmpfs   mounted on  /dev/shm

/dev/xvdb  mounted on  /mnt/data
```

But I could not find the location:  `/rdsdbdata/tmp anywhere`

So I'm not able to clear memory.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdXql.png)

Comment: In your case directory ` /rdsdbdata/tmp` is residing directly in the root partition `/` (first line of your `df` output). Do you have free space there?

Comment: I would presume you are using an RDS instance. You are not able to access that directly, but you can configure the RDS instance to have more disk space.

Comment: There is no /rdsdbdata folder on root. datasage answer could be correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I ssh into my server

Not really.  Your database is on an RDS instance, which can't be accessed over SSH.  You must have ssh'ed into your *web* server, instead.

RDS provides you with a managed server with MySQL -- and nothing else -- running on it.  It's not the machine where you were looking.  You can't perform any administration on the underlying server.  Everything -- including increasing the amount of allocated storage -- is done through the AWS console or API.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.MySQL.html

Comment: So increasing the memory is the only option, we cannot clean, right?

Comment: That's pretty much true.  `Innodb_file_per_table` is usually disabled by default on RDS, so removing data won't shrink the storage used.  There should otherwise be nothing *to* clean that you'd want to tinker with (binlogs and backups are not something you want to try to economize on, and they count in your storage allocation).

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, I started disliking AWS and their support is never there unless you shell out $200 for once in 6 months help

Comment: Qualified support technicians and engineers like AWS doubtless has on staff are expensive, so you really can't fault them for charging a premium for individualized support.  It's an excellent platform and much of it is very well documented, but there's a lot of reading required.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question? I am having the same issue and have increased the memory on the RDS instance and still no joy!! How do i increase the tmp dir memory allocation on RDS?